Wireguard not routing traffic back
I have 2 Ubuntu Servers with wireguard setup on them . one server is acting like middle man . so clients traffic is routed to middle server and middle server route them to the other server(I call it server 1 here) .
in my case the traffic routed completely from client to middle server and then to server 1 .
but it's not routed back to middle server so there is no internet when wireguard is connected.
the wg show output on server 1 is like this :
interface: wg0
  public key: Public-Key
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51880

peer: Public_key
  endpoint: [middle server ip:port]
  allowed ips: 10.0.0.0/24
  latest handshake: 1 minute, 21 seconds ago
  transfer: 7.34 KiB received, 372 B sent
  persistent keepalive: every 25 seconds

And here is my servers and client config :

server 1 config :

[Interface]
PrivateKey = Private-Key
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
ListenPort = 51880
MTU = 1500

PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ufw route allow in on wg0 out on eth0; ufw route allow in on eth0 out on wg0; ufw allow proto udp from any to any port 51880
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ufw route delete allow in on wg0 out on eth0; ufw route delete allow in on eth0 out on wg0; ufw delete allow proto udp from any to any port 51880


[Peer]
PublicKey = middle server Public-Key
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/24
EndPoint = [middle server ip:port]
PersistentKeepalive = 25


Middle server config:

[Interface]
PrivateKey = Private-Key
Address = 10.0.0.2/24
ListenPort = 52890
Table = 123
MTU = 1500

PreUp = ip rule add iif wg0 table 123 priority 456
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ufw route allow in on wg0 out on eth0; ufw route allow in on eth0 out on wg0; ufw allow proto udp from any to any port 52890
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ufw route delete allow in on wg0 out on eth0; ufw route delete allow in on eth0 out on wg0; ufw delete allow proto udp from any to any port 52890; ip rule del iif wg0 table 123 priority 456

[Peer]
PublicKey = Server 1 Public-Key
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
PersistentKeepalive = 25

[Peer]
PublicKey = Clint Public-key
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.102/32


Client Config(windows client):

[Interface]
PrivateKey = Private-Key
Address = 10.0.0.102/32
DNS = 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1
MTU = 1480

[Peer]
PublicKey = middle server Public-Key
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/1, 128.0.0.0/1
Endpoint = [Middle server ip:port]
PersistentKeepalive = 25

I tried changing port and Addresses but didn't work.
